# Testing CRUD function in Django Restaurant App

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing

I am wondering if someone could help me. I am trying to test some views in a Django restaurant bookings system app I have created. I am doing well with jut testing the views but now I want to test the CRUD functionality of certain pages. In particular the create a booking on the bookings page and then redirect it back to the home page once the booking was successful (as is what happens on the site)
I just can't seem to figure out how to do it. Here is my current code. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks

setUp:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):
"""
Testing of the views taken from
the views.py file.
All HTTP testing includes the base.html template
as well as the view being tested to make sure everything
is being tested as it would appear for a user
"""

def setUp(self):
   
    testing_user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='JohnSmith',
        first_name='John',
        last_name='Smith',
        email='johnsmith@email.com',
        password='RandomWord1'
    )

    Booking.objects.create(
        user=testing_user,
        name='John Smith',
        email_address='johnsmith@email.com',
        phone='123654789',
        number_of_people='2',
        date='2022-10-20',
        time='19:00',
        table='Window',
        occasion='none'
    )
```

test:

```
def test_add_booking(self):
 
    self.log_in()
    response = self.client.post('/bookings', {Booking: Booking})
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status's code of your response, then also compare the response content.

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
self.assertContains(response, "No bookins.")
```

Or even to be more precisely `self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context["the name"], ["with real content"]`